# PowerShell Format-List from different objects in the chain

Tags: powershell

How do I output properties from parent objects in a piped chain?

For example:

get-vm | get-vmdisk | forEach {Get-VHDInfo $_.DiskPath} | Select -Property Path, ParentPath, VM.VMElementName

Basically it's the VM.VMElementName that I'm wondering about (I made up that syntax). It's not the immediate object (which would be from Get-VHDInfo) but the grandparent (from get-vm) that I want to get a value for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get values from upstream cmdlets the way you want to. You can use foreach-object right after calling get-vm and save the value in a variable, then assign it back to the select-object as a new calculated property.

```
get-vm | foreach-object{    
    $VMElementName = $_.VMElementName   
    get-vmdisk | forEach {Get-VHDInfo $_.DiskPath} | Select Path,ParentPath,@{Name='VMElementName';Expression={$VMElementName}}
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed!  There was a slight issue with get-vmdisk not being bound to the results of get-vm so it over reports, so for the 3rd line I started it with $_ | and that did the trick.